# A problem about uniformly integrable over E?

Tags: lebesgue-integral

> Definition：let $\mathcal F$ be a family of functions,if for each $ε＞0$,there is a $δ＞0$ such that for each $f∈\mathcal F$,if $A⊆E$ is measurable and $m(A)＜δ$,then $\int_A |f|＜ε$. We say $\mathcal F$ is uniformly integrable over $E$.

> problem:let $\mathcal F$ be a family of functions,each of which is integrable over $E$ then $\mathcal F$ uniformly integrable over $E$ iff  for each $ε＞0$,there is a $δ＞0$ such that for each $f∈\mathcal F$,if $A⊆E$ is measurable and $m(A)＜δ$,then $|\int_A f|＜ε$.

From left to right is easy,only use the defition of uniformly integrable and a inequality, but conversely how to do?
This problem comes from Royden' real Analysis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose your family consists of real valued measurable functions.

Suppose the second condition is given. If $m(A) <\delta$ then (for any $f \in \mathcal F$) $m(A \cap \{x: f(x) >0\})<\delta$ so $|\int_{A \cap \{x: f(x) >0\}} f |<\epsilon$. But this is same as $\int_{A \cap \{x: f(x) >0\}} |f| <\epsilon$. Similarly $\int_{A \cap \{x: f(x) \leq 0\}} |f| <\epsilon$ Add these two finish the proof. .

Comment: Yes,$\mathcal F$ is consists of real valued measurable functions.But it seems not necessary to use the condition of each $f∈\mathcal F$ is integrable over $E$ from your Proof？

Comment: Each $f$ in the family is integragble over $A$ if $m(A) <\delta$. @user158796

Comment: I'm sorry i don't understand your words.Isn't this a condition？

Comment: $m(A)＜δ$,then $|\int_A f|＜ε$.i think that mean $f$ is integrable over $A$

Comment: @user158796 To show that$f$ is integrable over $A$ you have to consider the integral over $f\leq 0$ and the integral over $f>0$ as I have done in the answer.

Comment: But it seems to  haven't use $f∈ \mathcal F$ is integrable over $E$. The defition of uniformly integrable over $E$ is not need $f$ is integrable over $E$

Comment: @user158796 Right. I missed that condition in the second definition.